# GqlGen incorrectly generates directives that have colon character in value field

Tags: go, graphql, go-gorm, gqlgen

I use https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen for generating golang code from graphql schema. I need to be able to add gorm tags to the resulting golang types. For that, I declare a directive for custom go tags (in `schema.directives.gql`):

```
directive @goTag(
    key: String!
    value: String
) on INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION | FIELD_DEFINITION
```

Then I use it the following way in a graphql schema file:

```
type Value {
  value: Float!
  unit: String!
}

type Order {
    name: String! @goTag(key: "gorm", value: "primaryKey")
    amount: Value! @goTag(key: "gorm", value: "embedded;embeddedPrefix:dissolutionAmount_") 
    submitterRef String!
    submitter: Person! @goTag(key: "gorm", value: "foreignKey: SubmitterRef")  
}
```

Then I run code generation: `go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate` and the resulting code contains gorm tags that cut out text after ":" character:

```
type Order struct {
    Name              string    `json:"name" gorm:"primaryKey"` // <--- this is correct
    Amount          Value     `json:"amount" gorm:"embedded;embeddedPrefix` // INCORRECT - everything after "embeddedPrefix" is truncated: ":dissolutionAmount_" is missing, including trailing double quote
    SubmitterRef string. `json:"submitterRef"`
    Submitter       Person    `json:"submitter" gorm:"foreignKey` // INCORRECT - value in gorm tag is truncated, ": SubmitterRef" is missing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a bug in gqlgen around generating go tags that truncates everything after the colon. There is an [open PR](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/pull/2759) to fix that, hopefully they fix it soon.

As a workaround (until the code is fixed), I can probably create the model in go and map to the graphql type in gql config.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've found live to be better when I *always* define the models on my own, and bind with `@goModel()`, instead of trying to make gqlgen generate the structs. So this "work-around" might actually be the "best path forward" :-D